# Sending html email from VBA email program

Tags: html, vba

I have written an email program for my organization the handles some very specialized things very well, things I could use Outlook or Gmail for.  Now, the manager would like to send an occasional email to our small customer base, but I want the email body tto look professional and not send it as an attachment.  I have cobbled together an html document that present in all browsers and has been validated. My problem is I can't figure out how to point the message body at the html document.  Here is the salient code.

This is where all is set up:

```
Do While mailRs.EOF = False
'Me.AttachDoc = "C:\EmailFolder\CouponForm.pdf"
  emTo = mailRs.Fields("EmailAddr").Value
  emFrom = "SportsParkInfo@skokieparks.org"
  emSubject = Me.Subject
  emtextBody = Me.TextMessage
```

Here is a the call for sending the email

```
Call SendAMessage(emFrom, mailRs.Fields("EmailAddr").Value, _
                   emSubject, emtextBody, emAttach)
```

(I got the code for sending the email off the web and it works great through our mail server.)

In the above, before the call @ `emtextBody = Me.TextMessage` is where I need to replace `Me.TextMessage` with the address/body of the html document. And the message box is a textBox on the ACCESS form. I can't find any control in ACCESS that takes html. I can't use the path to the html document because that generates an error. Is there a way of getting around this

If more information is required I'll be happy to supply it.

Thanks for your time.

jpl

Comment: VBA may be limited in its support for the newer mail formats. In VB.NET I think there are two bodyFormats - text and HTML. You may be better off with a .NET application. You should provide a plain text option as well - some users set their preferences to plain text and some companies restrict HTML formatted email.

Answer (score 10):

Use something like the below code.  I've included elements for attachment as well as html formatting but pretty much anything you can write in html can also be done within vba.

```
Sub SharePerformance()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.createitem(0)
'& "<a href=""\\server\folder"">\\server\folder</a>" &
msg1 = "Team,<br><br><b><DL>" & Range("b5").Value & "</b><br><ul><b><u>" & Range("b6").Value & "</b></u>"
msg1 = msg1 & "<DT><a HREF=C:\USER\Desktop\File1.xlsb>"
msg1 = msg1 & Range("b7").Value & "</a><br>"
msg1 = msg1 & "<b><u>" & Range("b9").Value & "</b></u></DL><br><br>"


msg1 = msg1 & "<p><img src=file://" & "C:\temp\Chart1.png" & "></p>" & "<br>"

On Error Resume Next
' Change the mail address and subject in the macro before you run it.

With OutMail
    .To = Range("B1").Value
    .cc = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Range("B3").Value
    .HTMLBody = msg1
    '.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\temp\Chart1.png")
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\temp\Chart2.png")
    .display
End With
SendKeys "^{ENTER}"
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: My code was written for ACCESS 10, I am assuming the above code was for Excel.  Also assuming that msg1 contains the html.  My html doc has more than 100 lines. Not using Outlook.  Still struggling, but thanks jbay.

Comment: Yes it was but I was able to use the exact same code in access after selecting the microsoft excel object library from references and changing the cell references to direct somewhere else.  The number of the lines shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what code is inside that `SendAMessage` function you are using but all the VBA examples I've worked with seem to work the same way with the CDO.Message object like in this MS Knowledge Base article [KB286431](http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/286431). At some point `SendAMessage` is going to have a line that assigns the message object's `.TextBody` value to be equal to the `emtextBody` parameter you pass in.

One solution may be to copy your SendAMessage function into a new function SendAMessageHTML and replace the line where they are setting `someMessage.TextBody = emtextBody` so that you are setting `someMessage.HTMLBody = emtextBody`

Assuming your textbox has text along the lines of `"<html><head><body></body></html>"` you could modify your existing function to do a naive check like this:

```
if Left(UCase(emtextBody),6) = "<HTML>" then
  someMessage.HTMLBody = emtextBody
else
  someMessage.TextBody = emtextBody
end if
```

Comment: I the above suggestion:

Comment: In the above suggestion how do I address the html document if it is a folder.

Comment: Sorry for the fat fingers. You wrote  
One solution may be to copy your SendAMessage function into a new function SendAMessageHTML and replace the line where they are setting someMessage.TextBody = emtextBody so that you are setting someMessage.HTMLBody = emtextBody.  Say the html doc is in a folder;  HTMLBody = c:\htmlDocs\EmailDoc.html. How do I make that work?

Comment: You could find some VBA code to read that C:\htmlDocs\EmailDoc.html file into a String variable and then set your *.HTMLBody = myStringVariable*

Comment: Problem is the html document contains graphic images.  Can you convert to a string variable an html document that contains .jpg pictures.? Also, if html is converted to a string variable, how could it be read as email after it's sent. I am in uncharted waters here, at least for me.  Thanks for your time.