# Email VBA and HTML

Tags: html, vba, excel, email, html-email

I would like to send a complex Email using VBA and HTLM, but I cant achieve this.

I am used to sending simple Email, with some links and some variables, but what I need to do here is more complex.

I need to send an Email that looks like the one in this tutorial, but cant manage to deal with the HTML and HMTLbody.

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770

I've been researching, but cant find a way to properly code it.

Usually, my code looks something like this :

```
.HTMLBody = "Bonjour, les résultas d'essais sur :" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "<b>" & "Produit : " & "</b>" & produit & "<br>" & "<b>" & "Projet : " & "</b>" & codeproj & "<br>" & "<b>" & "Formule : " & "</b>" & formule & "<br>" & "<br>" & "sont disponibles !" & "<br>" & "Ceux-ci se trouvent dans le répertoire suivant : " & "<a href=""" & Chemin & lien & """>Lien</a > " & "<br>" & "<br>" & "Merci."
```

What I need is just some help to get started and the rest should be fine.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This looks like a good solution - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418891/sending-html-email-from-vba-email-program

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending html email from VBA email program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418891/sending-html-email-from-vba-email-program)

Comment: Than you to both of you. I'll give it a try !