# Change font and add bullets

Tags: html, excel, vba, outlook

How do I convert the script from an Mail_Object to HTML so that I can properly format line 3 and 4 to be bullet points and then change the font on line 5?

I know nothing about HTML.

The following code runs but does not do any formatting or bullet points.

```
Sub Sample_Auto_Generated_Email_Final()

    Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
        .Subject = "Report"
        .To = "XX@Xx.com"
        .Body = MAR_Message_5()
        .Send
    End With
End Sub



Function MAR_Message_5() As String
    MAR_Message_5 = "Line1" & vbNewLine & _
    "Line 2" & vbNewLine & _
    "     •  Line3" & _
    "     •  Line4" & vbNewLine & _
    Chr(10) & _
    "Line 5" <-- I want this line to be Calabri 6 point font.
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I test your code, please change your code to the below code:

```
Sub Sample_Auto_Generated_Email_Final()

Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    With Mail_Object.CreateItem(o)
        .Subject = "Report"
        .To = "XX@Xx.com"
        .HTMLBody = MAR_Message_5()
        .Send
    End With
End Sub



Function MAR_Message_5() As String

    MAR_Message_5 = "<span>Line1132323213123" & vbNewLine & "</span><br>"
    MAR_Message_5 = MAR_Message_5 & "<span>Line2132323213123" & vbNewLine & "</span><br>"
    MAR_Message_5 = MAR_Message_5 & "<span>????Line3132323213123" & vbNewLine & "</span><br>"
    MAR_Message_5 = MAR_Message_5 & "<span>????Line4132323213123" & vbNewLine & "</span><br>"
    MAR_Message_5 = MAR_Message_5 & "<span>........Line5132323213123" & vbNewLine & "</span>"

End Function
```

`<br>` label can switch to the next line.

This is my result:

[image]

Reference from:

[Sending html email from VBA email program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418891/sending-html-email-from-vba-email-program)