# Add two tables to an email

Tags: vba, email, ms-access

I am trying to add two tables with borders into my code for an email.

The result comes out as a table in a table with no borders.

The following is my result and syntax:

[image]

```vb
myitem.Display

Set ins = oOutlook.ActiveInspector

Set document = ins.WordEditor
Set Word = document.Application
Set selection = Word.selection

selection.TypeText Text:="Dear Requester,"
selection.TypeParagraph
selection.TypeParagraph

With selection
    .Font.Bold = True
End With
selection.TypeText Text:="Please confirm that quotation of chosen vendor is suitable before proceeding with PR creation."
selection.TypeParagraph
selection.TypeParagraph

'add table here
Set objTable = selection.Tables.Add(Range:=selection.Range, NumRows:=3, NumColumns:=2)
objTable.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
objTable.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
objTable.Borders.OutsideColor = wdColorBlack

objTable.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Initial quote :"
objTable.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = " "
objTable.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Discount rate :"
objTable.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = ""
objTable.Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Final quote :"
objTable.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = ""

selection.TypeParagraph
selection.TypeParagraph

Set objTable2 = selection.Tables.Add(Range:=selection.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=2)
objTable2.Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
objTable2.Borders.OutsideLineWidth = wdLineWidth150pt
objTable2.Borders.OutsideColor = wdColorBlack

objTable2.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Last spend on year 2020 :"
objTable2.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = " "
objTable2.Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Incremental increase percentage :"
objTable2.Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = ""
```

I tried adding the `selection.TypeParagraph` function but the line breaks keep adding inside the table, not after or before the table.

Comment: Why did you add tag for vbscript? This code is in Access? You want to build tables for an Outlook email message? Why are you using Word objects?

Comment: I apologize for the wrong tags. Yes, this code is in Access. Yes, I want to build tables for an Outlook email message. Sorry, could you explain what Word objects are? I am new to coding and I am not familiar with a lot of the terms.

Comment: You are use Word objects, commands, properties. HTML code tags would probably be simpler. Example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29418891/sending-html-email-from-vba-email-program. VBA tag was appropriate, vbscript did not make sense.

Comment: I see... I will try coding in html then.

Comment: Hi tried coding in html but the whole code turns red

Comment: Where is rest of code: declaring variables, what is myitems.Display, how do you output tables? Code provided should be self contained and issue reproducible. Help us help you. It's been a long time since I looked at this editor for Outlook coding.

Answer (score 0):

Using Word objects and properties seems overly complex for Outlook message. Here is example of building two tables using HTML code tags.

```
Dim strT As String, strC As String, strH As String
strT = "width='500' style='text-align:left;border:2px;font-family:calibri;border-collapse:collapse;padding:5px'"
strC = "style='border:3px solid black' width='50%'"
strH = "<table " & strT & ">" & _
"<tr><td " & strC & ">Initial quote : </td><td " & strC & "></td></tr>" & _
"<tr><td " & strC & ">Discount rate : </td><td  " & strC & "></td></tr>" & _
"<tr><td " & strC & ">Final quote : </td><td " & strC & "></td></tr></table><br>" & _
"<table " & strT & ">" & _
"<tr><td " & strC & ">Last spend on year 2020 : </td><td " & strC & "></td></tr>" & _
"<tr><td " & strC & ">Increment increase percentage : </td><td " & strC & "></td></tr>" & _
"<tr><td " & strC & ">Final quote : </td><td " & strC & "></td></tr></table>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Decided to combine the 2 tables in 1. Leaving an empty row.

```
myitem.Display
  
  Set ins = oOutlook.ActiveInspector
 
  Set document = ins.WordEditor
  Set Word = document.Application
  Set selection = Word.selection
   
    selection.TypeText Text:="Dear Requester,"
    selection.TypeParagraph
    selection.TypeParagraph
    
    With selection
    .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    selection.TypeText Text:="Please confirm that quotation of chosen vendor is suitable before proceeding with PR creation."
    selection.TypeParagraph
    selection.TypeParagraph

'add table here
    With selection.Tables.Add(Range:=selection.Range, NumRows:=6, NumColumns:=2)
        .Range.Font.Bold = True
    
        .Cell(1, 1).Range.Text = "Initial quote"
        .Cell(1, 2).Range.Text = ""
        .Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = "Discount rate"
        .Cell(2, 2).Range.Text = ""
        .Cell(3, 1).Range.Text = "Final quote"
        .Cell(3, 2).Range.Text = ""
        .Cell(4, 1).Range.Text = ""
        .Cell(4, 2).Range.Text = ""
        .Cell(5, 1).Range.Text = "Last spend on year _2020_ :"
        .Cell(5, 2).Range.Text = ""
        .Cell(6, 1).Range.Text = "Incremental increase percentage :"
        .Cell(6, 2).Range.Text = ""
    End With
```